# Want to know about internationalization,angular translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

I want to learn clearly about internationalization and angular translate.I want to know whats the difference between two and any demo or working example for that. I watched demos that has option to select language and sentences change according to that.But i want a demo where the text changes automatically according to locale. anyone can help me?

Comment: Without access to location services, how will you determine locale? And why would someone's geographic location determine their preferences? It seems to me you wish to know a user's language preference, not their locale.

Answer (score 0):

Acording locale you may use `navigator.languages` some like this

```
function getLocale() {
    if (navigator.languages != undefined) {
      return navigator.languages[0];
    } else {
      return navigator.language;
    } 
  }

  var locale = getLocale();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vorant/pc4dh05j/